# react/lib/update - multiple splices, multiple indexes

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

While working with `react-dnd`, and using the `update` utility of react ('react/lib/update'), in structure like below :

`state = {
  data : {
    items : []
    /* array of 'fields' (flat objects items), and 'groups' (object that may have nested 'fields' under 'group.nested') */
  }
}`

I noticed a some problem with the `update` utility, when trying to move `field` from the `items` array, into group (the `nested` array in the `group` object).

I tried to delete the field (with `splice`), then add it to the nested array.
The result of this `update` function returned the group, with the field nested inside, though that field wasn't removed from the original position with the declared `$splice`.

### you can find below, an RunKit with a detailed example with the issue

https://runkit.com/592da/splice-react-update-issue

Will be glad to receive any advice, or any better-practice solution.

Thanks !

Comment: I was able to make it work with [this npm package](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) called `immutability-helper`, which solve effortless it with keeping the same syntax of react/lib/update.
I think the issue there is because the react/lib/update utility is not able to work with non-object specs like arrays in different indexes.

Hope it will help someone conflicting with same issue,
though if someone has better solution using `react/lib/update` please let me know.

Thanks